# Javascript joining table cells ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We're working on a website which has a page that displays a schedule with different schedule items in them, all these items have certain values attributed to them and they're all original/unique. The way we generate this schedule makes it so that I cannot use rowspan or colspan. I came up with the idea to use javascript, a client side language to redo parts of the table when the server is done spitting out the table. The problem is that I don't know alot of javascript , in the 2 pictures below, ill explain what I want to accomplish[image]

The first column on the left is a column of each lesson and how long it lasts. Each lesson lasts 3 hours, as displayed by the black outline. What I want to do with javascript is create a system that detects when 3 lessons in the same column have the same classcode (Which I hid in this example) and same room, and joins them together as one block of data. so instead of filling every  with the same class and room, fill those 3 cells with 1 block that shows the class and room.

I would love some feedback about the idea and if it is possible at all.

Comment: it's possible, but would probably be very awkward. You you "can't" use rowspan or colspan, but why not? I'm sure you could generate the schedule a different way if you really wanted to. That'll likely be less painful than trying to mangle the table afterwards.

Comment: Or, you could consider using a ready-made calendaring tool such as [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs) (there are others, but that's a good one) to display your events. It has already solved the problem of how to put events on a grid in this kind of way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from you. You can not use rowspan when you generate the table but you can use it afterwards. So, I wrote the following code. Let me know if you need clarification but the code is pretty self exploratory.

Basically we loop through values for the column that you want and we check it against next values in next rows and we calculate the rowspan based on that loop then we remove the extra cells

> Dont forget to change value of `columnToMergeNumber = [2, 3];` to the column numbers of your table

```js
var columnToMergeNumber = [2, 3];
$(document).ready(function() {
  columnToMergeNumber.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });
  calcmergeCells();
});

// sloop through rows and cells to get current value and value of row span
function calcmergeCells() {
  var numberOfRows = $("#MergeTable").find("tr").length + 1;
  for (var j = 0; j < columnToMergeNumber.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 1; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
      var currentValue = $("#MergeTable tr:nth-child(" + i + ")")
        .find("td:nth-child(" + columnToMergeNumber[j] + ")")
        .html();
      var times = mergeNTimes(currentValue, 1, i, columnToMergeNumber[j]);
      mergeCells(i, times, columnToMergeNumber[j]);
      i += times - 1;
    }
  }
}
// Find out the value of rpowspan
function mergeNTimes(currentValue, times, index, column) {
  var nextValue = $("#MergeTable tr:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ")")
    .find("td:nth-child(" + column + ")")
    .html();
  if (nextValue == currentValue) {
    return mergeNTimes(currentValue, times + 1, index + 1, column);
  } else {
    return times;
  }
}

// Delete cells and add rowspan
function mergeCells(fromRow, times, column) {
  for (var i = fromRow + 1; i < fromRow + times; i++) {
    $("#MergeTable tr:nth-child(" + i + ")")
      .find("td:nth-child(" + column + ")")
      .remove();
  }

  $("#MergeTable tr:nth-child(" + fromRow + ")")
    .find("td:nth-child(" + column + ")")
    .attr("rowspan", times);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="MergeTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I go about using this code on multiple columns one after the other. i.e. changing columnToMergeNumber to integers from 1 to 7 to redo every column.

Comment: @coder I have updated the code now all you need to do is put column number in columnToMergeNumber as in the example